# code-first Local no data loading

Tags: winforms, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, code-first

I have a generated SqlCe.4.0 Database by EntityFrameWork 4.3.1 code-first (updated nu-get package).

System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer is set via sampledata and database is generated correct, but when I attempt to read from database for displaying in DataGrid, no data is loaded. That means: In debug the DbSet.Local.Count is always Zero, but I can iterate DbSet items all are shown in debugconsole.

What is wrong?

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

What's in DbSet.Local is what DbContext is tracking - so if you query a database and get some entities then they will be visible in DbSet.Local. Take a look at this article from Julie Lerman http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781018.aspx there is a section about DbSet.Local.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
Of course it should, but isn't.I know the article.